# Wait some seconds before agent's reply

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm trying to build a very simple Dialogflow app for Actions on google.

What I had in mind was a very simple timer, but every X seconds the agent will tell the user "X seconds left".

I'm using the Fulfillment section on dialogflow. What I've tried to do was a simple "setTimeout" that include another agent.add but this seems to be ignored by Dialogflow when I deploy it:

```
function startTimer(agent)
  {
    agent.add("Timer started! 20 seconds from now.");

       setTimeout(function(){ 
        agent.add("10 seconds left!");
    }, 10000);  

    agent.add("Time out.");
}

    let intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set('timer', startTimer);
    agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
```

The response from assistant is a simple "Timer started" and "Time out", without the X seconds remaining. Is there any way to add a reply when an intent is started? Thanks!

---

EDIT | as suggested, I have tried with SSML, but the tags are displayed on the screen when they get said by the assistant.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

  function startTimer(agent)
  {
    agent.add("Something to say");
    agent.add(`<speak><seq><media begin="30s"><speak>30 seconds</speak></media><media begin="30s"><speak>1 minute</speak></media></seq></speak>`);
    agent.add(new Suggestion(`Quit`));
  }

    let intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set('timer-go', startTimer);
    agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to an Action start a conversation, the fulfillment code (your function) must return within 10 seconds, or the Google Assistant will close the Action with a time-out warning.

And your setTimeout is not working because this code is running in the cloud, and to actually send it back to the Assistant, you must send the response, and you are only adding items to it, but not returning the object.

[This page](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment/how-it-works) from DialogFlow documentation explains how the back-end fulfillment works on DialogFlow / Google Assistant.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SSML in your response and set when to respond.

e.g.

```
<speak>
  <seq>
     <media begin="0s">
        <speak>Timer started! 20 seconds from now</speak>
     </media>
     <media begin="10.0s">
        <speak>10 seconds left!</speak>
     </media>
  </seq>
</speak>
```

Also, [check](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml) for more information.

Comment: This looks interesting, thanks! I've tried to put something like that in my code: 

`agent.add("Timer start...");
    
        const ssml = '<speak>' + '<seq>' +
    '<media begin="0s"><speak>30 seconds</speak></media>' +
          '<media begin="30s"><speak>1 minute.</speak></media>' +
    '</seq></speak>';

    agent.add(ssml);`

It kinda works, the main problem is that everything in the ssml is displayed on the screen. How can I avoid that?

Comment: You can use ` for multiline string and this won't be displayed on screen.  `agent.add(\`<speak>
                <seq>
                  <media begin="0s">
                    <speak>Timer started! 20 seconds from now</speak>
                  </media>
                  <media begin="10.0s">
                    <speak>10 seconds left!</speak>
                  </media>
                 </seq>
               </speak>\`);`

Comment: I still see the tags as the assistant reply. Is that because of the test version?

Comment: No, I dont think so. Which simulator do you use? Actions on Google or dialogflow?

Comment: I have tried with the simulator on Actions on Google and the test version that I can invoke on the phone.

Comment: Hey, I tried that as well and seems fine. No ssml displayed on the screen. If, you can share the code you use, maybe I can help

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know how to add a long piece of code here so I've edited the original post. I've putted everything I have in the fulfillment.

Comment: I will try as soon as possible and let you know

Comment: You should try them all in one function like: `agent.add(\`<speak><seq><media> <speak> Something to say</speak> </media><media begin="30s"><speak>30 seconds</speak></media><media begin="30s"><speak>1 minute</speak></media></seq></speak>\`,new Suggestion(\`Quit\`));`

Comment: Still nothing... the tags are always displayed on the screen. I've tried to replicate it with the Intents section on DialogFlow, and I've achieved it with a Simple Response under the Google Assistant tab, putting the ssml in the audio output section and something else in the display section. In this way the ssml isn't displayed. I've tried to do a Simple Response with code in the fulfillment, but without success (I can't really find some examples on how to use this on code).

Comment: If you are doing this for Actions on Google, you may consider to use "actions-on-google" library. You can find guides for that. If you are interested you can start with this codelab. (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-1/index.html?index=..%2F..index#5)